# How to minify page.content PhantomJS

Tags: phantomjs

Want to compress `page.content` before logging into console.

Just logging `page.content`  gives spaces, which is not needed.

Comment: Related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/466437/minifying-html I would say, don't do it.

Comment: Also related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19018921/minify-html-using-a-node-js-module but it's not directly usable in PhantomJS